# Irony DotNet VariableImplementation Syntax error

Tags: c#, .net

I am a beginner with the irony framework in DotNet.
I want to parse the syntax like "int identifier".
My first try was to create a class and inerhit the Grammar class.

```
using Irony;
using Irony.Parsing;
using Irony.Interpreter;

public class SimpleGrammar : InterpretedLanguageGrammar
{
    public SimpleGrammar() : base(false)
    {
        NonTerminal root = new NonTerminal("root");
        IdentifierTerminal s = new IdentifierTerminal("identifier");
        root.Rule = "int " + s;
        this.Root = root;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Grammar grammar = new SimpleGrammar();
        LanguageData language = new LanguageData(grammar);
        Parser parser = new Parser(language);
        ParseTree parseTree = parser.Parse("int test");
    }
}
```

The Property ParserMessage in the ParseTree has the content "{Syntax error, expected: var }".
What is the reason for that?

Best regard

Comment: I've replaced the partial pieces of code you've shown with a [mcve] - but the result of that is a `NullReferenceException` in `Parse`... could you compare this with your actual code?

Comment: Note that when I change the code to derive from `Grammar` instead of `InterpretedLanguageGrammar`, I don't get an exception but I also don't get the message you're talking about... Basically, if we're going to help you, we need to be able to reproduce the problem. Please edit the code to make it reflect your real code, with the error you're getting.

Comment: Hello,
Please make sure that,  the rule of the root has a space after the int. root.Rule = "int " + s;

Comment: I copied the code you had presented.

Comment: I changed the code, about 2 min ago.

Comment: Right. I'll have a look when I get some time, but that won't be for a couple of hours. (This is why it really helps if you can present a [mcve] from the start...)

Comment: Okay, so I'm not getting "Syntax error, expected: int " (not `var` as per your question). I suspect you just don't want that space...

Comment: Hello,
Sorry i get the message: {Syntax error, expected: int } instead of var.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hello,
I want the space between "int" and the variable name.
For instance: int test;
How can i describe this rule?

Comment: Are you sure the space isn't implicit in the + operator? Without the space, it does manage to parse your example, after all. (I haven't used the library myself before...)

Comment: Hello,
my opinion is, that the framework is ignoring the white spaces.

Comment: If it did that, surely it wouldn't matter if you removed the space...

Comment: How can i force, that the user have to do a whitespace.
Without whitespace in the rule the expression can be parsed.

Comment: If you remove the space from `"int "` in your rule then it *won't* parse `inttest` but it *will* parse `int test`. Surely that's what you want.